# Getting a JWT from SAP Commerce Cloud 2105

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, sap-commerce-cloud

I have installed SAP Commerce Cloud 2105 on my machine locally and I am able to register a user in it and get the access and refresh token for it using a client (the client that I registered using an impex). The token information that I am getting is of the format,

```
{
    "access_token": "h-KvY9G0buec1XskUU4svyA8ntY",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "MZtBODmWe8m0Vzygpui8JDY7D5Q",
    "expires_in": 43199,
    "scope": "basic openid"
}
```

Can I configure SAP Commerce to return me a JWT instead of a simple token? I have looked into backoffice and client information but couldn't find a clue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an external dependency like java-jwt auth0 and sign the payload with you own private key. Inside your custom JWT you can add your custom claims or the entire OAuth object.